# How did 'exagium' (weighing) semantically shift to mean 'essai' (trial, attempt, essay)?

Tags: étymologie, latin

What semantic notions underlie "a weighing, a weight" and 'trial, attempt'?

> ## [essay (n.)](https://www.etymonline.com/word/essay?ref=etymonline_crossreference#etymonline_v_11631)
>
> 1590s, "trial, attempt, endeavor," also "short, discursive literary composition" (first attested in writings of Francis Bacon, probably in imitation of Montaigne),
> **from Middle French *essai* "trial, attempt, essay" (in Old French from 12c.),
>
> from Late Latin *exagium* "a weighing, a weight"**
> from Latin *exigere* "drive out; require, exact; examine, try, test,"
> from *ex* "out" (see [ex-](https://www.etymonline.com/word/ex-?ref=etymonline_crossreference)) + *agere* "to set in motion, drive"
> (from PIE root [*ag-](https://www.etymonline.com/word/*ag-?ref=etymonline_crossreference) "to drive, draw out or forth, move") apparently meaning here "to weigh." The suggestion is of unpolished writing. Compare [assay](https://www.etymonline.com/word/assay?ref=etymonline_crossreference), also [examine](https://www.etymonline.com/word/examine?ref=etymonline_crossreference).

Comment: You needn't go back to PIE. The Latin meaning "try" as in "I will try to express my arguments" is more than clear, isn't it?

Comment: @Nico I don't think you addressed 'weighing' though?

Answer (score 2):

From another dictionary (*Dictionnaire étymologique de la langue française*, Bloch & von Wartburg):

> **essai** lat. *exagium* "pesée" (dér. de *exigere*, au sens de "peser"), qui est attesté dès le IVe s. au sens de "essai"

To weigh has been used with a figurative meaning (to measure, to test) for a long time, surely because it was one of the few accurate measurements that you had in Antiquity. For example Latin *pensare* became both French words **peser** and **penser**.

Comment: [figurative meaning]